# Setting default font in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, font

Is it possible to set the default font in ArcMap 10.4.1 to Times New Roman?

Answer (score 4):

Never tried myself, but it seems you can do something in the menu `Customize` -> `ArcMap Options`.

Here you'll find a `Data View` page where you can set the fonts for the labels.

[image]

A similar option is also present fot the `Tables` page.

This won't basically change your fonts "application-wise", but for labels and tables only.

[image]