# Problem displaying Hebrew-language in Attribute tables (ArcMap 10.2)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, attribute-table, encoding, hebrew

Recently I migrated my ArcGIS project unto a new computer, both PCs using the ArcGIS Desktop ArcMap 10.2 software. The databases and projects are in Hebrew.
However, when I came to open the attribute files, all I see is gibberish. However, the software seems to be able to properly present existing labels and present them on the map nonetheless.
As the main files havan't been changes, this seems to be a software definitions issue.
Anybody came across something similar?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user please take the [Tour]. Please [edit] the question to indicate what data format the data source is in. You should also indicate any differences between the environment variables on the two systems (especially any NLS variables).

Comment: Related https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/328821/276